# jquery/userscript is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

In chrome my userscript cause the error

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

But the line @require includes jquery. At least i know it does with greasemonkey (does chrome not support that?)

If i delete the function that one function call (which makes $ = jQuery) I get the error $ is not defined. In firefox/greasemonkey it runs fine

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Detect Duplicate IDs
// @namespace   jkbfvsdjkzsvfshefsdvh
// @description Alerts you when more than one ID is on a page
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant
// ==/UserScript==

//using localhost in @include doesn't seem to work
if(location.hostname!='localhost')
    return;

//Ignore above for console.
(function($){
$(function() {
var checkDupeIDs = function () {
    var dupes = [];
    var ids = [];
    $('[id]').each(function(i,e){ids.push(e.id)});
    var len = ids.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        if(dupes.indexOf(ids[i])!=-1)
            continue;
        for(n=i+1; n<len; ++n) {
            if (ids[n]==ids[i]) {               
                dupes.push(ids[n]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dupes.length!=0) { 
        for(i=0; i<dupes.length; ++i)
            console.warn('Multiple IDs #' + dupes[i]);
        alert(dupes.join('\n')); 
    }
}


var jHtml = $.html;
$.html = function () {
    checkDupeIDs();
    return jHtml.call(this, arguments);
}

checkDupeIDs();

})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include jquery in your project

Comment: Do you have it included in your page? example: `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js">` (Two ways here: http://dabrook.org/blog/two-ways-to-include-jquery-in-your-document)

Comment: @gaurav: @ require includes jquery. At least it does with greasemonkey

Comment: the script you're using says:
`// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

So you need to add this line to your file.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight out of the box, Chrome does not support Greasemonkey scripts very well  ([Out-of-date table](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/wiki/Comparison-Table), [Out-of-date page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts)).  The `@require` directive does not work, for example.

To enjoy almost complete compatibility for your Firefox Greasemonkey scripts, install [the Tampermonkey Extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).  Your script should work in Tampermonkey.

Also, to avoid problems in Firefox, do not leave `@grant` blank.  Use `@grant  GM_addStyle`, if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Check two most important things:

1. You have included jQuery in your project
2. You have included jQuery file before any other js file that uses jQuery

Comment: @ require includes jquery. At least it does with greasemonkey